# Show that if A is similar to B with similarity matrix T, and B is similar to C with similarity matrix P, then A is similar to C

Tags: linear-algebra

By definition A is similar to B with similarity T means $B=TAT^{-1}$

What I did:
$B=TAT^{-1}$ and $C=PBP^{-1}$ hence $C=PTAT^{-1}P^{-1}$.

Then I couldn't figure out how to continue, since $AB≠BA$ in matrices I don't think I can simply switch one positions to get  $PP^{-1}=I$.
How to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

as you noted:

$B=TAT^{-1}$ and $C=PBP^{-1}$ hence $C=PTAT^{-1}P^{-1}=$

so:

$=(PT)A(PT)^{-1}$

Comment: Thank you, that is it. Just noticed how stupid my question is, sorry. Will mark your answer as correct one when they let me do so.

Comment: You are welcome!